# How do I Send Buttons to Background/Disable Them Depending on Choice?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I send certain buttons to the background and/or disable them depending on what a user chooses? Let's say a user clicks, "iphone 3GS" and all the buttons are enabled and able to be clicked but if, "iphone 4" is chosen then the, "unlocked" button is sent to the background/disabled. If possible, can if statements be used for this function? if ("iphone4") disable ("unlocked, AT&T"), for example. I'm open to jquery but I'm not to familiar so a little detail must be included telling me how to use it.

Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nwxLM/

Here's a portion of the script:

```
if (q1 == "AT&T" && q2 == "8GB" && q3 == "Black" && q4 == "Black") {
            $('#next_button').val('att 8gb black').click(function () {
                window.location.href = 'http://google.com/'
            });
```

Here's a portion of the HTML:

```
<div class="radio" id="form">
            <div class="tablebuttons" type="radio" name="q4" value="iPhone-3GS">
                <img width="50px" height="50px" 
src="http://wepriceit.webs.com/Images/iPhone-3GS.png" />
            </div>
```

The full code is in the jsfiddle located above.

Comment: @gibberish Yes I'm open to jquery but I'm to familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use a template framework, like underscorejs or mustachejs, and when you render your html piece you can implement some conditionals.

a template file sample, using underscore.js:

```
<div class="div-filter">
    <ul class="ul-filter">
        <%var ind =0;
         _.each(types, function(type){ %>
            <li class="li-filter">
                   <img id=<%='img-'+type.name %>
                        notes-id=<%=ind%>
                        class="large-img" 
                        src=<%= 'img/tipo/' + type.name + '.svg' %>  
                        alt=<%="'" + type.name + "'"%> />
            </li>
        <%ind++;
        });%>
    </ul>
</div>
```

How to use with javascript:

```
var _tpl = _.template(pTpl);
$(_element).html(_tpl(_typesNotes));
```

So what's not implicited? You need to load the underscorejs lib, and load the template file.

An alternative, I believe that this works:

```
$(".elements").on("click",function(){
    $(this).off();
    var elements = $(".elements");
    for (c=0; c < elements.length; c++){
        if($(this).id!==elements.id){
            $(elements).css("display","none");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry but that's the first time that I've ever seen this. It's seems understandable but I wouldn't even begin to know how to implement this.

Comment: that's an elegant way, but you also can set the display property to none `display:none`

Comment: Can you provide me an small example with my code and if it's simple then I'll continue with it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36895/discussion-between-user2680614-and-claudio-santos)